# Django clear media files every 24hrs

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

Im creating a project where i require all media to be deleted at a 12am every day so there is a new fresh start.

how would i go about doing this within my django project.

Comment: Probably should just write a simple script deleting all the files in the media folder and run it as a CRON job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Writing a django-admin command to delete all files

How to write a custom django-admin command

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-management-commands/

2. Using task(windows) or cron(linux) to execute the django-admin command at 12am.